# How to get the count of data under a document under a collection?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "user-followers". I basically need to display the total number of followers. Just not able to figure out the completion block to get the count. There are resources that help me get the count of the documents under a collection but what about the values inside a document. This is how the data is stored in firestore:

```
Collection: "user-followers"
 Document: "abc"
  "user1":1
  "user2":1
  "user3":1
```

I want the count of the number of users under document "abc", which is 3.

There are resources for getting count of all the documents but what about the count of data inside the document.

Comment: Are you storing user1: 1, user2: 2 etc as fields within the document? If so, that's not going to be a good way to store your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure storing your data like that is the best idea but it appears you are asking how to get a count of the fields within a document.

A simple solution is to count the child data, which will be three in this case.

```
func countFields() {
    let collectionRef = self.db.collection("user-followers")
    let documentRef = collectionRef.document("doc")
    documentRef.getDocument(completion: { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let q = documentSnapshot?.data()?.count
        print(q)
    })
}
```

The documentSnapshot?.data() is a dictionary which can be iterated over, counted etc.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported by default, but you have several ways to go around that. (unless you are ok querying the whole collection to get the numbers of records... this means everything, literally everything)

- Cloud Functions

```
 import * as functions from 'firebase-functions' 
 import * as admin from 'firebase-admin' 
 const firestore = admin.firestore()
 const counterRef =  firestore.collection(`counters`)
 export const keepCount = functions
  .firestore.document(`user-followers/{doc}`).onWrite(async (change, _context) => {
    const oldData = change.before
    const newData = change.after
    const data = newData.data()

    if (!oldData.exists && newData.exists) {
        // creating
        return counterRef.doc(`user-followers`).set({
          counter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
        })
      } else if (!newData.exists && oldData.exists) {
        // deleting
        return return counterRef.doc(`user-followers`).set({
          counter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
        })ID)
      } else  {
        // updating - do nothing
        return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
})
```

Now you only have to fetch `counters` collection, the doc value is your collection name `user-followers`, and the prop is counter... you can apply this patter with all the collections you need to keep track of the counter...

- Other third-party cache tools

You always can use other tools like algolia or redis to keep track of this, but well they cost more money.

I would apply the cloud function to get started.

Comment: The feature is built and fully supported. You just need to work with documentSnapshot.data() (a Dictionary) instead of the documentSnapshot itself.

Comment: that is partially true, you need to query the whole collection in order to the total which is total overkill in the majority of cases

Comment: Ah - I think that's what you missed. It's not a collection - it's a single document *within* the collection the OP is asking about. He wants to know how many fields there are within that document.

Comment: Yes this doesn't answer the question directly, but again I learnt something new, which I did not know before. Thanks @andresmijares